# How to organize stateful WCF web services with custom session handling

Tags: wcf, web-services, session

Consider a company with a large set of functionality to be exposed via web services. A subset of this functionality is used for building up some very complex and computation intensive scenarios, and requires a session to be maintained during this iterative build-up. Each scenario targets one single base structure, representing, say a single customer. That is, a scenario is a series of heavy operations on a single customer structure. The operations can be grouped by which area they target, but basically all operations in the same scenario roots in the same customer structure.

The following decision is given from the outside, and cannot be altered: an already made custom session handler must be used, which basically operates on a session given a simple GUID-token to be send to/from the client. Therefore, from a technical perspective the session need not to be limited to a single service, but can live across multiple services.

Besides the stateful operations, there is also a number of stateless operations.

Given the above decision about the custom session handler, the question is now: how should all these operations be organized? What organization is most elegant?

Some possibilities:

- All stateful operations are gathered in one single stateful service, while all stateless services are grouped in an arbitrary set of services, possibly by which area they target. Possible problem: the single stateful service can become very large.
- Both stateful and stateless operations are grouped into smaller services, but stateful and stateless operations are still separated so that no service contains both stateful and stateless operations. Possibly, all session estabilshment and finalization can be put in a separate thin dedicated service, say `SessionService`. With this a approach we have no huge single stateful service. But is the organization elegant? Why force a strict separation of the stateful and stateless operations at all?
- Group all operations by their target, ignoring their statefulness. This gives a number of services with mixed stateful and stateless operations. The former can take the session GUID token as input argument, and a service behavior can take care of automatically handle the session estabilshment given some appropriate naming convention for the session key/token.
  Similar to above, a separate dedicated service can take care of session establishment and finalization.
- Something else, not mentioned above?

Which organizaion is the most elegant?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented what is basically your third option. We have 20+ operations, some of which check the request for a SessionID (GUID), some of which do not (like Ping() and Login(DeviceID)). All the session handling is "Custom" in the sense that we're not using WCF persistant sessions; rather, we've created a Login() function that takes a GUID, ID, Password from client requests for authentication.

On Login(), we validate the DeviceID, UserID and Pwd against the DB, creating a row on the Session table containing StartTime (session only good for <8 hrs) and DeviceID. We then send back to the client a SessionID (GUID) that he/she uses in all subsequent connections, whether uploading or downloading.

As far as organization is concerned, the subs and methods are organized by the device type (iOS, PC, Android) and the type of operation, just to keep the apples from the oranges. But each function that's Session-related always authenticates the request, validating the inbound SessionID. That may seem wasteful, checking each session with each request (again and again), but because we're using BasicHTTPBinding, we're forced to use a stateless model.